# Java lower bound wildcards

Tags: java, wildcard

I'm struggling to get my head around this and was wondering if someone could explain the reasons for this.

I have three classes:

```
class Angel {}
class Person extends Angel {}
class Employee extends Person {}
```

When I attempt to execute this code

```
public static void insertElements(List<? super Person> list){
    list.add(new Person());
    list.add(new Employee());
    list.add(new Angel());
}
```

I get an error:

```
The method add(capture#5-of ? super Person) in the type List<capture#5-of ? super Person> is not applicable for the arguments (Angel)
```

I had always read the documentation to mean `<? super X >` meant any type of X or a superclass of X (so in my case, Angel is a superclass of Person) and should be permitted? Obviously not!

Does anyone have any simple examples?

Comment: To help me, can you please write the relationship between  Employee, Person, Angel classes ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your intuitive logic says "a `List<? super Person>` is a *list of things that are a `Person` or a supertype of `Person`*, so naturally I can add an `Angel` into it". That interpretation is wrong.

The declaration `List<? super Person> list` guarantees that `list` will be of such a type that allows anything that is a `Person` to be added to the list. Since `Angel` **is not a `Person`**, this is naturally not allowed by the compiler. Consider calling your method with `insertElements(new ArrayList<Person>)`. Would it be okay to add an `Angel` into such a list? Definitely not.

The best way to reason about it is that `List<? super Person>` is no definite type: it is a *pattern* describing a range of types that are allowed as an argument. Look at `List<Person>` as not a subtype of `List<? super Person>`, but a type that matches this pattern. The operations allowed on `List<? super Person>` are those that are allowed on any matching type.

Comment: Thanks Marko, your answer makes perfect sense. Could I follow up with one question then...what is the difference between ? super and ? extends. I always read ? extends to be ezxactly as you have described ? super. (ie: anything that is-a Person)

Comment: `List<? extends Person>` is a list of Persons or something narrower. In that case you are guarenteed to **get** something that is a Person from it, but you won't be able to add anything of your own into it, because you don't know how narrow the list is.

Comment: In order to do its type erasure work, the compiler has to concretize a wildcard into a specific boundary type. It uses inference.  Step 1: compiler infers it's a `List<Person>`.  Step 2: the compiler verifies that `List`'s `add` method is getting a `Person` or a subtype of `Person`.  The clue here is that the compiler says ``CAP#1 extends Object super: Person from capture of ? super Person``.  It helps me to think of 'Object super: Person' as _an object of which Person is a supertype_, or more simply, **an object of type Person**.  An Angel is not a person, so it fails compilation.

Comment: You state "The declaration List<? super Person> list guarantees that list will be of such a type that allows anything that is a Person", but is not that the description of List<? extends Person>. I find that very confusing and not a clear distinction at all.

Comment: @AndrewS `List<Boy>` conforms to `List<? extends Person>`. But I can't add a `Girl` to that list. Clearly, `List<? extends Person>` does not guarantee I it will be something I can add anything that is a `Person` to.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  Thank you for responding so promptly. Could you address List<? super Person>  in your response to my question as that is what I was asking about.

Comment: @AndrewS `List<Angel>` conforms to `List<? super Person>`  because `Person extends Angel` and indeed, I can add any `Person` to it. `List<Boy>` does not conform to `List<? super Person>` and I can't add any person to it.

Comment: Lower bound is very poorly defined on the official oracle pages, even literature for OCP examination struggles to convey thorougly but here I finally get it

Answer (score 18):

For me, none of these answers were clear enough, although they helped me. After looking a lot, and I mean a lot, I finally came up with the easiest explanation for wildcards:

```
public class CatTest {

    public class Animal {}
    public class Cat extends Animal {}
    public class MyCat extends Cat {}
    public class Dog extends Animal {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Cat> catList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<MyCat> myCatList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>();

        CatTest catTest = new CatTest();
        // Here you are trying to add a MyCat instance (in the addMethod we create a MyCat instance). MyCat is a Cat, Cat is an Animal, therefore MyCat is an Animal.
        // So you can add a new MyCat() to a list of List<Animal> because it's a list of Animals and MyCat IS an Animal.
        catTest.addMethod(animalList);

        // Here you are trying to add a MyCat instance (in the addMethod we create a MyCat instance). MyCat is a Cat. 
        // So you can add a new MyCat() to a list of List<Cat> because it is a list of Cats, and MyCat IS a Cat
        catTest.addMethod(catList);

        // Here you are trying to add a MyCat instance (in the addMethod we create a MyCat instance). MyCat is a Cat.
        // Everything should work but the problem here is that you restricted (bounded) the type of the lists to be passed to the method to be of
        // a type that is either "Cat" or a supertype of "Cat". While "MyCat" IS a "Cat". It IS NOT a supertype of "Cat". Therefore you cannot use the method
        catTest.addMethod(myCatList); // Doesn't compile

        // Here you are adding a MyCat instance (in the addMethod we create a MyCat instance). MyCat is a Cat. 
        // You cannot call the method here, because "Dog" is not a "Cat" or a supertype of "Cat"
        catTest.addMethod(dogList); // Doesn't compile
    }

    public void addMethod(List<? super Cat> catList) {
        // Adding MyCat works since MyCat is a subtype of whatever type of elements catList contains
        // (for example Cat, Animal, or Object)
        catList.add(new MyCat());
        System.out.println("Cat added");
    }
}
```

At the end, these are the conclusions:

When working with wildcards, **wildcards apply** to the **type of the list** passed as an argument to the method, **not to the type** of the **element** when you try to add an element to the list. In the example, you get the following compile error:

> The method addMethod(List) in the type CatTest is not applicable for the arguments (List)

As you can see, the error is about the method signature, and not about the body of the method. So you **can only pass lists** of elements that are either "Cat" or super type of "Cat" (`List<Animal>, List<Cat>`).

Once you pass a list with the specific type of elements, you can **only add** elements to the list that are either "Cat" or a subtype of "Cat", that is to say, it behaves **as always** when you have a collection of elements! You cannot add an "**Animal**" to a list of "**Cat**". As I said before, **wildcards don't apply** to the elements themselves, the restrictions apply only to the "List". Now, why is that? Because of simple, obvious, well known reasons:

```
Animal animal = new Dog();
```

**If you could add** an "Animal" to a "Cat" list, you could also add a "Dog" (a "Dog" is an "Animal"), but it is not a "Cat".

Comment: **emphasis** is enough, no need for uppercase.

Comment: how **bold** you are.

Answer (score 2):

There is a severe understanding as I always did, `List<? super Person>` is introduced to ensure `List<Person>` and `List<Angel>` can both be passed in as an argument which is the flexibility [*upper bounded wildcard*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) provides.

But **within the method**, in your case only `Person` or subtype of `Person` can be inserted into the list which ensures the list will always contain valid instances.

E.g. if you are passing in a list of `Person`, then only `Employee` and `Person` can be inserted while `Employee` will be auto-type-casted to `Person`.

Comment: 1. `List<? super Person>` is not *upper bounded wildcard*; it is *lower bounded wildcard*. 2. You can't insert an `Angel`(subtype of `Person`) instance into the list within the method. You can only insert `Person`, `Employee` instance or `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it the other way around: For the type bound on `List<? super Person>`, `List<Person>` is obviously a valid type for the parameter.
If the compiler allowed your code, it would allow you to insert something of type `Angel` into a `List<Person>`.

Comment: yes, that is what he wants to do, so explain why, not just that is doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards basically allow you to specify a type range for a parameter, in your case when you write

`public static void insertElements(List<? super Person> list)`, the compiler will allow you to pass a List of either Person or any of its super types. Lets see a concrete example

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
List<Angel> angels = new ArrayList<>();
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

insertElements(objects);      // Works fine, Object is super type of every type
insertElements(angels);       // Works fine, Angel is super type of Person
insertElements(persons);      // Works fine, Person itself
insertElements(employees);    // Error, Employee is neither Person itself nor its a super type of Person
```

**Now lets see why are you getting that error**

From above code we know that you can pass list of persons, angels or objects to the `insertElements` and it will work fine, Now lets say you invoke the method with list of persons. so list is now `List<Person>` and you do `list.add(Angel());`

this essentially means you are trying to do `Person person = new Angel();` this assignment is not type compatible and you get the error.