# Can a method using super take a subtype of an object and add it to the list?

Tags: java, generics, subtyping

So the function below is supposed to be a function that takes a `Car` object and adds it to a `Col<>` object.

```
void insertCar(List<? super Car> c, Car x) {
   c.add(x)
}
```

The question asked whether if adding a variable `n` of type `Nissan` object to a variable `c` of type `List<Car>` would work (ie. `insertCar(c, n)`)

The answer is yes but I'm not sure why. I thought adding subtypes of an object `Car` would not be possible because of the use of `super`. That it would only take types of type `Car` or any supertype of `Car`.

Anyone able to me understand?

**EDIT Is it that...**

I wouldn't be able to add a Nissan if the `List<>` itself was of some other subtype being passed in? For example, if `List<? super Car>` was actually `List<? super Ford>`

There seems to be conflicting answers below but this is a question provided for exam review so pretty sure the question and answer provided are correct.  It's just my understanding of it is what I'm not sure about.

Comment: `Nissan` is a subtype of `Car`?

Comment: Yeah, it's a subtype of Car

Comment: if Nissan is a subtype of Car then the answer is NOOoo, Col<Nissan> is not Col<? super Car>

Comment: Can I replace `Col` with a `List`? You didn't say what it is.

Comment: Also, what is `C<Car>`? is `C` supposed to be `Col`?

Comment: It's supposed to be anything sort of collection but that's fine.  I'm a little confused because it seems like conflicting responses

Comment: This is not a generic method, your title is wrong. Also, don't add "Java" in the title, that's what the tags are for.

Comment: Ok I made the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question asked whether if adding a variable `n` of type `Nissan` object to a variable `c` of type `List<Car>` would work (ie. `insertCar(c, n)`)

To put your words to code, I believe this is what you are talking about:

```
public class GenericCheck {

    static void insertCar(List<? super Car> c, Car x) {

        c.add(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Car> c = new ArrayList<>();
        Nissan n = new Nissan();
        insertCar(c, n);
    }
}

class Car {}

class Nissan extends Car {}
```

Yes. this is fine, but there are 3 type checks needed to be done:

1. Is `List<Car>` a valid 1st argument for `insertCar`'s `List<? super Car>`? **Yes**, it is a subtype, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) for example.
2. Is `Nissan` a valid 2nd argument for `insertCar`'s `Car`? **Yes**, it is a subtype.
3. Is the call `c.add(x)` valid? **Yes**, the argument `x` must be of type `Car` or a supertype of `Car` as defined by `List<? super Car> c`, and it is so by the definition `Car x`.

So why is it confusing? Because you pass to the second argument a `Nissan` type, and *think* that now point 3 will break because `x` is not of the type `Car` or a supertype of `Car` (it is a subtype). What happens is that `Nissan` is being upcasted to a `Car`, which is then a viable argument.

Remember that to know if the call `c.add(x)` is valid, all you have to do is look the definitions of `c` and `x` (in the method's arguments list). This ensures that as long as the method is called with valid arguments, the call `c.add(x)` is valid. This check is unrelated to the (two) type checks when calling `insertCar`. Those are the 3 checks we performed above.

**Edit:**  So why does `insertCar(List<? super Nissan> c, Car x)` not work?

Because of type erasure. During compilation, the compiler erases all type parameters and replaces each with its first bound (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)). What you get is a request for `List<Nissan>` to `add(Car)`. But this can't compile because `Car` is not a subtype of `Nissan`.

In the first case of `List<? super Car>`, type erasure would result in `List<Car>` and then `add(Car)` is valid.

What, I think, will clear your confusion the most is the realization that generics provide *compile-time-only* checks. As I alluded to above the block of code

```
static void insertCar(List<? super Car /* or Nissan */> c, Car x) {

    c.add(x);
}
```

has to compile regardless of what arguments the method is called with at *runtime*. This means that the generics in the 1st method argument have nothing to with the type you pass to the 2nd argument: `insertCar(..., Car)` or `insertCar(..., Nissan)` do not affect the compilability of `c.add(x)`. The given argument is converted (upcasted) to the method's argument type `Car` and this is irrelevant to the content of the method.

Comment: Right, that's the reason why I'm confused.  Is it that I can pass it a Car but if the list was actually List<? super Ford> I would not be able to pass the Nissan object?  I'm trying it now in code from what you provided.

Comment: @cpd1 What is `C<? super Ford>`? You want to change the definition of `c` in the arguments list or as defined in `main` (you named them both `c`)?

Comment: Sorry about that, it was meant to be list.  I think I'm just not clear on the upcasting.  I don't remember it being discussed at all in class so confused still why it works the way it does.  I thought changing the list to some subtype of Car that is not Nissan that it wouldn't work, which was the case.  But by the same logic, I tried List<? super Nissan> but I wasn't able to add a Nissan

Comment: @cpd1 You have to be very specific about what you change to what and where exactly. "*I tried List<? super Nissan>*" doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry.  Thanks for being helpful.  I mean the signature for insertCar.  I changed that to List<? super Nissan> thinking that I could still pass in an Nissan object but it didn't compile

Comment: Thank you.  I think I'm mixing up my thoughts in terms of the subtyping handling.  I know that I wouldn't have a relationship between List<Car> and say List<Vehicle> (where Vehicle is a super type) and that's why I needed to add super to let this occur.  I just didn't think I can then add an object to it that is a subtype but I think I get it now.  A Nissan is a Car and has all the properties of a Car or more so it's ok to add it to the list.  But what I cannot do is add a Vehicle to this list because then it can lead to a run type error if a method expects a Car

Comment: thank you very much for your help!  I think I get it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98043/discussion-between-cpd1-and-user1803551).

Comment: @cpd1 I think this will also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623189/java-lower-bound-wildcards

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that as well!

Answer (score 0):

> The answer is yes but I'm not sure why. I thought adding subtypes of
>   an object Car would not be possible because of the use of super. That
>   it would only take types of type Car or any supertype of Car.

Any super class reference can hold the object of its instance or any of its child class instance and hence this is completely legal.

Comment: you probably need to check what type co-contravriant is

Comment: Ok I think I might have been misunderstanding as I'm stressed ha.  Am I right in that the issue is that I wouldn't be able to add a Nissan if the Col<> itself was of some other subtype being passed in?  For example, if Col<? super Car> was actually Col<? super Ford>

Answer (score 0):

Your subtype objet will have at least all the attributes and methods from the Car object, plus normally more methods of its own. If a Nissan object is assigned to a Car variable, you could call all the methods of a Car variable. The contrary, assigning a Car instance to a Nissan object would not be possible, because a Nissan object could have more methods than a Car instance has.

Comment: you probably need to know more about generics