# Can anyone explain this code using bounded wildcards in java?

Tags: java, lower-bound

I  know my question may seem like a duplicated one but i  have read many of the similar questions and answers yet I am confused specifically with lower bounds (? super) .
Please consider this code .

```
 import java.util.*;
   public class Main {
  // just adds numbers to the List nums
   static void myadd(List<? super Number> nums){
    
    nums.add(1);
    nums.add(1.0f);
    nums.add(1.1);
    nums.add(3l);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      List empty= new ArrayList<>();
      myadd(empty);
      System.out.println(empty);
  }
}
```

[Here](https://onecompiler.com/java/3yb8ydu8s) is the Link to execute it .

According to oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html)

> a lower bounded wildcard restricts the unknown type to be a specific
> type or a super type of that type

**[Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#:%7E:text=Class%20Number&text=The%20abstract%20class%20Number%20is,int%20%2C%20long%20%2C%20and%20short%20.) class is the superclass of classes  Double, Float, Integer, Long, and Short then why this method executes perfectly fine ?**
This method (myadd) should only work for objects which are direct instances of Number class or  it's super type , not for it's sub classes.

I have read following answers still my doubt is not clear .

1. [Understanding upper and lower bounds on ? in Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795709/understanding-upper-and-lower-bounds-on-in-java-generics)
2. [Java lower bound wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623189/java-lower-bound-wildcards)

If anyone can explain I will be obliged.

Comment: You can call your method `myadd` only with a `List<? super Number>` or a `List<Number>` or a `List<Object>` (because `Object` is the only supertype of `Number`). That's it. Oh, I forgot the _raw type_ `List`, but you shouldn't use it at all.

Comment: Are you asking about `myadd(empty);` or the fact that your `add(..)` calls all compile?

Comment: It's hard to understand where you have your problems. To which line exactly does your question "why this method executes perfectly fine" refer to?

Comment: It says nums is the list of any subclass of Number.

Comment: @ChengThao According to oracle docs  <? super > means any same or  super class of that type   not subclass  ?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose  my problem is  int float double are not super classes of Number , the only super class is Object  . Then why I am able to add int float double to my list as according to the definition of lower bound i should only be able to add  Object class ( only super class of Number ) not subclass of Object class (int  float double..) ?

Comment: First of all you are dealing with `Integer`, `Float` and `Double` - not with `int`, `float` and `double`. Second, an `Integer` is an `Object`, so you can use an `Integer` everywhere, where an `Object` is expected. That is a fundemental rule in polymorphism.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you it is respective  wrapper classes of int, float, double . But Integer is a subclass of Object class(basically subclass of Number) & if sub classes are also allowed in " ?super " then what is the difference between extends & super?

Comment: @BigIO, you are correct.  That was what I was thinking but the writing came out wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List<? super Number>` means that only `List<Number>` (or some superclass of `Number`, which is `Object`) can be assigned to that variable (`nums`, in your example).

Because any `Long`, `Double`, etc. is-a `Number` instance, it can be contained in a `List<Number>`—or, for that matter, a `List<Object>`. However, if you were to assign an element from the list to another variable, the variable would have to be of type `Object`, since the actual type of the list could be `List<Object>`.

`List<? extends Number>` would mean that `List<Number>` or `List<Long>` or `List<Double>` or any other subclass of `Number` may be assigned to that variable.

Because such a list is permitted to contain only a certain subclass of `Number`—like `Long` or `Double`—but the particular subclass is unknown, nothing can be safely added to the list. Any of its elements can be assigned to a variable of type `Number`, however.

Consider the following examples:

```java
List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>();
List<? super Number> nums = objs;
// objs is `List<Object>` so clearly this is fine:
objs.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
objs.add("Hello, World!");
// We've forgotten that nums is actually the same `List<Object>`, so this won't compile:
nums.add("Nice to meet you!"); 
// But we remember that nums is at least a `Number` so this is okay:
nums.add(Double.valueOf(1.0));
// This won't compile, because `nums` could/does have a `String` in it:
Number num = nums.get(0);
// This is okay; nums could hold any superclass of `Number`
Object obj = nums.get(0);
```

---

> Then what is the difference between both of them because ultimately i am able to add subclasses of Number in both extends & super ?

No, this is wrong. As I said, "Because such a list is permitted to contain only a certain subclass of `Number`—like `Long` or `Double`—but the particular subclass is unknown, nothing can be safely added to the list." You can't safely add a subclass of `Number` (or anything) to a `List<? extends Number>`. The `?` doesn't mean "any subclass"; it means "unknown subclass". It's a list of some subclass of `Number` that you don't know.

```java
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Number> alias = ints;
// This won't compile, because you'd be polluting `ints` with a float.
alias.add(Float.valueOf(1F));
List<Number> anyNum = new ArrayList<>();
// These adds are fine, anyNum can contain any subclass of Number
anyNum.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
anyNum.add(Float.valueOf(1F));
// This is fine...
alias = anyNum;
// ...but these will fail, because we "forgot" that anyNum points to List<Number>
alias.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
alias.add(Float.value(2F));
```

> Please Justify what you said in 2nd paragraph of your answer you said " Because any `Long`, `Double`, etc. is-a `Number` instance, it can be contained in a `List<Number>`—or, for that matter, a `List<Object>`" I don't agree since `Long`, `Double` all these wrapper classes are not instances of `Number` class. Instead they are instances of sub-classes of `Number` class.

I used some jargon there, ["is-a",](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) with which you may be unfamiliar. When one class is a subclass of another, it should be fully substitutable for the superclass. A `Long` or a `Double` can perform any operation a `Number` can; we say that a `Double` "is-a" `Number`. An assignment like `Number x = Integer.valueOf(1)` is perfectly fine because `Integer` is-a `Number`. And of course, `nums.add(x)` would be perfectly fine, because the type of `x` is `Number`. Would a (widening) cast from type `Child` to type `Parent` succeed? Then `Child` is-a `Parent`.

> However I agree with this line "if you were to assign an element from the list to another variable, the variable would have to be of type `Object`, since the actual type of the list could be `List<Object>`." because when i tried to assign a value from the list to a Float variable I had to typecast it to float .This raises more qestion because if List can only accept Object then why it is accepting Integer , FLoat .. in myadd() method???

A variable of type `List<?>` means that the list has some type, but we don't know what it is. Nothing can be safely added to it, and if we take an element from it, all we know about the type is that it is an `Object` or any subclass, thus we can only safely assign it to `Object`. Don't think of `List<?>` as "a list of any type", but as "a list of unknown type."

A variable of type `List<Object>` contains anything that "is-a" `Object`. Since any type ultimately extends `Object`, any type can be added to this list.

A `List<Number>` contains anything that "is-a" `Number`. `Long`, `Double`, etc. have that "is-a" (subtype) relationship with `Number`, so they can be added to the list. I can define my own custom `Number` type and add it to the list.

A variable of type `List<? extends Number>` means that the list has some type, but we only know that the type is `Number` or a subclass. We still can't add anything to it safely, because we don't know if it's an alias for a `List<Long>`, `List<Double>`, or what have you. But, if we take an element from it, we can assign it to `Number` instead of `Object`, because we know at least that it is-a `Number`.

A variable of type `List<? super Number>` means that the list has some type, but we only know that the type is `Number` or a superclass. We can add anything that "is-a" `Number` (which includes subclasses). But, if we take an element from it, we don't know it is a `Number`; the alias could point to a `List<Object>`, so it might contain objects of any class. We can only safely assign its elements to variables of type `Object`.

You can't use wildcards when you instantiate a generic type. That is, you can't write `new ArrayList<? extends Number>`. Wildcards are only used like an alias. A value with no wildcard is only *aliased* under a type with a wildcard, whether during assignment to a variable, passing as a parameter, or returning as a method result.

I keep using the word "safely", because Java generics are about type-safety. If you don't suppress or ignore any type-safety warnings, you won't have any class-cast exceptions at runtime unless there is a corresponding explicit cast in your code. If you suppress or ignore type-safety warnings, you might encounter a class cast exception from a point in your source code where no cast is visible. The compiler inserts these implicit casts for you in order to support generic types.

Back to your original example, let me rewrite it and ask you where your question lies.

```java
static void myadd(List<? super Number> nums) {
    /* Create Number objects */
    Number anInteger = 1;
    Number aFloat = 1F;
    Number aDouble = 1D;
    Number aLong = 1L;
    /* Add Number objects to list */
    nums.add(anInteger);
    nums.add(aFloat);
    nums.add(aDouble);
    nums.add(aLong);
}
```

Do you not understand that a `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, and `Long` can be assigned to a `Number`? Or do you not understand that a `Number` can be added to a `List<? super Number>`?

Comment: Then what is the difference between both of them because ultimately i am able to add subclasses of Number  in both extends & super ?

Comment: Please Justify what you said in 2nd paragraph of your answer you said " Because any Long, Double, etc. is-a Number instance, it can be contained in a List<Number>—or, for that matter, a List<Object>"  I don't agree since Long, Double all these wrapper classes are not instances of Number class. Instead they are instances of  sub-classes of Number class.

Comment: However I agree with this line "if you were to assign an element from the list to another variable, the variable would have to be of type Object, since the actual type of the list could be List<Object>." because when i tried to assign a value from the list to a Float variable I had to typecast it to float .This raises more qestion because if List can only accept Object then why it is accepting Integer , FLoat .. in myadd() method???

Comment: @BigIO I tried to address your questions in an update to my answer.

Comment: I was not able to comprehend that sublcasses (Is-A relationship) of Number  can also be added to ?super Number since it IS-A Number after all .

Comment: Excellent! I think it's great that you have a desire to really understand how things are working. Too many developers lack that interest.

Comment: With your last code snippet   and elaborative  explanation now I understood this-                             In List<? extends Number >  we can add any Number or subclasses(IS-A)  of Number & while assigning we can  assign it to Number since we know it is at least a Number ( that's why it is called Upper Bound).

Comment: Now in case of List<? super Number> any element which is Number or its super class ( Object can be added to it . Since sub class of Number class  IS-A Number too so we can add that too . But when it comes to assigning we can only assign Object safely since we  it can be an Object too ( that's why lower bound )

Comment: So finally   I can say <? extends Number > -- Number or sub class of Number & while 
                                   assigning only Number can be taken safely ( Upper Bound )                                                                                                                      <? super Number) -- Number (including sub classes of Number which forms IS-A 
   relationship with Number class)    or Super class of Number          
 i.e.  Object & while assigning only Object can be taken safely  (Lower Bound)

Comment: @BigIO I think you have it just right on assigning elements *from* the list *to* a variable, with the upper and lower bounds. (This is often called "consuming" a generic type.) But on adding elements to the list, it sounds like there is still some confusion. You can't (safely) add *anything* to a `List<? extends X>`. To a `List<? super X>` only `X` (subclasses but not its superclasses) can be safely added. (Passing a generically-typed argument like `list.add(x)` is sometimes called "producing".)

Comment: thank you but I am a rookie in the world of developers  and this is my first question . I really did not expected that i will get to learn about  so many things in just question . Thank you for  your elaborative yet simple explanation .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246902/discussion-between-bigio-and-erickson).