# Generics-why can you add a child of T to a List<? super T>

Tags: java, generics, collections

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19231762/1498827

```
public class Test {

    public class A {}

    public class B extends A {}

    public class C extends B {}

    public void testContraVariance(List<? super B> myBlist) {
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        myBlist.add(b);
        myBlist.add(c);
        A a = myBlist.get(0); // does not compile
    }
}
```

If myBlist accepts a super type of B ,which means B or up, then why can you also add a child to it as in `myBlist.add(c)` ?

Comment: Because `C` is implicitly convertible to `B`. It would be odd to prevent `myBlist.add(c);` but to allow `B tmp = c; myBlist.add(tmp);`. They do the same thing, so why would you want to force users to write unwieldy code? (Or `myBlist.add((B) c);` where the cast is guaranteed to succeed...)

Comment: This question was just closed as a duplicate of a question whose answer was cited in this question. Presumably the OP has read that question and other answers and is seeking clarification about this particular answer. OP can you clarify your question? (Reopened.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the question is specifically about the meaning of `List<? super B>`. The OP wrote "`myBlist` accepts ... B or up" and I think this is the root of the misunderstanding. `List<? super B>` does **not** mean a list that can only contain elements of type `B` or of a supertype of `B`.

Instead, `List<? super B>` is a list whose *type parameter* is `B` or is a supertype of `B`. Given the type hierarchy in the question, and this declaration:

```
public void testContraVariance(List<? super B> myBlist)
```

then `myBlist` can be a `List<B>`, a `List<A>`, or a `List<Object>`. *Any* of these types can contain a `C`. That's why `myBlist.add(c)` works.

Answer (score 1):

Every `C` [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `B`. You should be comfortable with the notion of assigning an instance of `C` to a variable of type `B`:

```java
B c = new C();
```

From there, it should not be surprising that this is valid:

```java
List<? super B> myBlist = new ArrayList<Object>();
myBlist.add(c);
```

Comment: See also [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73142781/3474) where I struggled mightily to convey this understanding.